# Browser Back Button using protractor or javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I am writing an automated test for the browser back button on logout of an angular application using a combination of protractor and cucumberjs.

When trying to use the command `history.back()` I get the following error:

```
 ReferenceError: history is not defined
        at World.<anonymous> (/Users/&&&&&/&&&&&/features/step_definitions/browsers.js:62:16)
```

This points to where I'm calling the history.back(); function.

How do I fix this, or correctly implement a browser back function using cucumber js?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

In your protractor test:

```
browser.navigate().back();
```