# How to click browser back key in protractor

Tags: protractor

I'm kind of new to Protractor and I'm writing a protractor script for my Angular js application.

In my application there is a place that I need to click on browser back button and not sure how to do it.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23739066/browser-back-button-using-protractor-or-javascript)

Used `browser.navigate().back();` to click the browser back button. :)